# Recursive function inside foreach loop php

Tags: php, loops, recursion, foreach

```
$parents = array(
    array('id'=>1,'parent_id'=>0,'title'=>'Parent1'),
    array('id'=>2,'parent_id'=>1,'title'=>'Child1'),
    array('id'=>3,'parent_id'=>1,'title'=>'Child2'),
    array('id'=>5,'parent_id'=>3,'title'=>'Child2.1'),
    array('id'=>6,'parent_id'=>5,'title'=>'Child2.1.1'),
    array('id'=>7,'parent_id'=>5,'title'=>'Child2.1.2'),
    array('id'=>8,'parent_id'=>7,'title'=>'Child2.1.2.1'),
    array('id'=>9,'parent_id'=>2,'title'=>'Child1.1'),
    array('id'=>10,'parent_id'=>0,'title'=>'Parent2'),
    array('id'=>11,'parent_id'=>2,'title'=>'Child1.2'),
    array('id'=>12,'parent_id'=>6,'title'=>'Child2.1.1.1'),
);

function childParentTree($parents,$parentId = 0) {

    $str = '';
    foreach($parents as $parent):
        if($parentId == $parent['parent_id']) {
             // Create Label
             $str .= '<li>'.$parentId.$parent['title'].'</li>';
             // search Child
             $str .= childParentTree($parents,$parent['id']);
        }
    endforeach;

    return $str;
}

echo childParentTree($parents);
```

The above code is ok, but when I dry run the code I am confused by the results. After printing

```
0 
1
2
9
```

for the variable `$parentId` it prints 11
That means the previous parent id, but how

Can someone explain why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Other than tweaking for this code sandbox, it looks like it works https://3v4l.org/LYmK4

Comment: Use something like Xdebug to step through the code and you can find out **exactly** what's happening

Comment: It's entirely unclear what you mean by "_for the variable `$parentId` it prints `11`_" since that is a local variable inside loop that makes a recursive function call. This is like saying "_in the ocean there is a fish_". At what point in time did that variable have a value that you did not expect it to have and what did you expect instead? The question is entirely ambiguous. The code does what I expect it to do.

Comment: Thanks sir, my question is when the $parentId is 2 it start the foreach loop with searching all the array and find the first match in id=9, prints it and call the recursion with the total array and $parent['id'] that is = 9, then the foreach startsthe search in the array to match $parentId == $parent['parent_id'] doesn't find anything in the loop then comes out of the loop at that time I think the $parentId will be still 9, but It prints 11, that means it searches inside the loop with $parentId=2 else how he get the value 11, please enplane this part.